# How can I link Domain users with Local users for Terminal Server connections

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, user-management, terminal-server

I have a strange setup. I have a terminal server with local users to that Terminal Server. The Terminal server is on the domain The program that is being accessed, can't get Domain users, so we are limited to the local users on that server.

Both The DC and the terminal server are Windows Server 2012 R2. Users all have Windows 10, and sign in using Domain Credentials.

We have an issue with confusion between the different usernames, and I'm trying to create a seamless experience when connecting to the Terminal server. I'm tired of resetting passwords.

I've done research and I found that you can create a trust relationship between 2 separate domains, so turning the terminal server environment into a separate domain would be that direction, however the naming scheme of the users is different. Creating a separate domain for those users isn't out of the question.

Is there a way to link SIDs. Like **DC/USER** opens RDP session and it is automatically configured to **Terminal/User-123**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: No, that is not possible.

Long answer: The major problem seems to be the "architecture" of this "strange setup". Things like "The program that is being accessed, can't get Domain users" will not be solved by adding even more Domain Users and more Domains.

Comment: I figured as much. The developer is stubborn and doesn't want to add ldaps support. I'm just trying to clean up some technical debt and make unified passwords across "domains"